# how to write this 404 rule in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, http-status-code-404

I  have a custom CMS. It works very well except for one thing. I am wondering how best to implement 404 functionality. The site should only have the following url types

```
index.php?upn=something
```

or

```
gallery.php?groupId=2
```

Any directories that are appended to the url after index.php or gallery.php should throw 404's. Also I would like to throw a 404 if the content is not found in the database when a upn is specified. I realise that I can throw the header in php. But I said I would try to get a little more insight into this problem overall. So if ye have any info or pointers I'd appreciate them.

Comment: "Also I would like to throw a 404 if the content is not found in the database" Not possible via apache conf

Comment: because you want to check database content, you MUST send status code by PHP!

Comment: thanks guys, I understand that about the php. I was really after the apache for the first bit and just some pointers on anything I need to look out for in the php. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to do this programatically from my PHP code. You could write some simple Route Component, that try to find what you want. Today you're routing just to actions (`index.php?upn=` and `gallery.php?groupId=`) but someday in the future you may add new one, and you should change your .htaccess, which is more difficult. If you do it all in your app tier you can change it simpler.

Paste this code in a .htaccess file at the root of your project, and will route every request to router.php. Once you have the request you can decide what action to do.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ router.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for this I really like this router idea as I do similar actions for building database queries all the time. Great answer thanks a million.

Comment: You're welcome. Take a look at CakePHP router. It works like that, and can be useful to take a look at the code. Maybe you can use something else. Also, there may be some library for routing out there

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to return the 404 in the php code, but you can set the 404 handler like so in htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/notfound.html
```